# snackbar fills up the screen when soft keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-snackbar

I am showing a snackbar when the user clicks on a link in the chat, works fine in general but just noticed that if I leave the soft keyboard up and then try joining the link the snackbar fills the entire screen. Looked around for a solution but could not find one. Need help or direction to any post that has the solution and I missed it.

[image]

```
public static void showConversationLinkSnackbar(View view, int resId) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(view, view.getContext().getString(resId), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Comment: Add your code .

Comment: @ADM: added the code, I hope this is what you were looking for, please suggest something.

Comment: Add your layout XML and . Method 'showConversationLinkSnackbar' calling too .